# find and replace text inside quotes ignoring html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have simple text with HTML tags and some text in quotation marks I want to add span on text inside quotes. for example:

```
<p>A quick "brown" fox "jumps" over <a href="www.gamescottage.com">the</a> lazy dog.</p>
```

And I want is to change this line to something like this:

```
<p>A quick "<span>brown</span>" fox "<span>jumps</span>" over <a href="www.gamescottage.com">the</a> lazy dog.</p>
```

and I am using this this code to do this :

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function (){
        var text = $('p').html();
        text = text.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, '"<span class="quote">$1</span>"');
        $('p').html(text);
     });
</script>
```

but it replace quotes of HTML anchor tag as well any solution?
In short I just want to add `span` inside quotes ignoring quotes of HTML tags.

Comment: So you want to remove the `b` in `brown` ?

Comment: @adeneo that's typo..and should not be removed...

Comment: @C-linkNepal - how do you know, people ask for the strangest things ?

Comment: as jumps is not changed....The OP just want to wrap quoted text in span tag...

Comment: That's not relevant, maybe the OP just wants to replace `b`'s. Anyway, I realize it's probably a typo, but when asking for specific replacements, getting the before and after results right, is rather important.

Comment: @adeneo no I want to add `span` inside quotes but it effects href quotes as well

Comment: @Mubeen1992 while you're seeing such comments, you should have updated your question...

Comment: @C-linkNepal Do you have any suggestions about this?

Comment: @Mubeen1992 Sorry, I don't know regex very well.

Comment: Are all characters allowed between quotes or only alpha(numeric)?

Comment: all characters are allowed

Comment: If you don't know regex, then you should learn it. There are many similar SO questions you can refer.

Comment: You almost have it right, you match the string correctly but when you do the replace you are overwriting thé quotes with the span tags, add those before and after the span tags in the second argument for replace()

Comment: @Alex this is not exact problem. Problem is when it replace quotes of anchor tags `href` attribute as well but I don't want to replace that

Comment: After you do the first operation of adding the quotes to span tags, why don't you run another which runs only on anchor tags and places quotes around the href

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript already has a built on DOM parser for you - instead of trying to parse HTML with a regular expression which is inherently difficult and borderline impossible - you can use the built in abilities the DOM brings you. In your case I'll demonstrate it using jQuery but a non-jQuery solution is equally simple:

```
$("p"). // all p tags
contents(). // select the actual contents of the tags 
filter(function(i,el){   return el.nodeType === 3; }). // only the text nodes
each(function(i, el){ 
    var $el = $(el); // take the text node as a jQuery element
    var replaced = $el.text().replace(/"(.*?)"/g,'<span>"$1"</span>') // wrap
    $el.replaceWith(replaced); // and replace
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p67k0euo/).

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in three separate steps:

1. temporarily replace quotes in HTML tags with a marker
2. add spans to any remaining quotes
3. restore quotes where any markers were put

Step 1:

`text = text.replace(/([^>"]*)"(?=[^<]*>)/g, '$1#Q#');`

This uses a lookahead to see whether the quote is followed by a `>` before the next `<`

Step 2:

`text = text.replace(/"(.*?)"/g, '<span class="quote">$1</span>');`

Step 3:

`text = text.replace(/#Q#/g, '"');`

Comment: Really? If you're going to downvote a solution that works, you'd better back it up with a reason.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I assume you are good at regex and scripts . Here is a algorithm using which you can write your code.

*after replacing text with spans as you do in ur current code, take the resultant string and check for if any span tag present inside a open html tag (Ex: `<a ... <span>`) and replace that whole HTML entity from the original String. By this you can achieve what you need.*

Note: I have done the same in Java once I dont have the snippet with me now

Hope this helps you